# Create password for apps with seahorse

Tags: seahorse

I am trying to have passwords for apps on my ubuntu, basically I have another installation where when I go to passwords and LOGIN part there is nothing on the right and I expect it to have items like on this picture, how to do this, can someone give me more details what needs to be done?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR12R.png)

Comment: you don't create passwords inside seahorse but within the apps. The apps will put this in the ubuntu password store.

Comment: What do they put into it? Why is it connected with login? I am assuming that maybe apps are putting this into login as keyring part? is it something else?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You don't create passwords for apps in the **Gnome Keyring** (`seahorse` is  just the name of a gui frontend for the keystore). They will do by themselves once you installed / started them or used some functionality within these apps.

All the apps in the screenshot have an internal password store. They put the master password for that store into the Gnome Keyring for you.

This has the benefit that the apps password store can be encrypted on disk, but users have the convenience not needing to put a password, because the Gnome Keyring gets automatically unlocked after you entered your password at the ubuntu login screen.

---

However, you can also use the ubuntu keystore for your own tasks if you wish. You can create a password by clicking the **`+`** in the titlebar -> Password.

You can also use `secret-tool`, a CLI tool to store and lookup passwords, e.g.:

```bash
secret-tool lookup application chromium
```

However, for sensitive passwords I'd always prefer `pass` or `keepassxc`, as these are not tied to your user account and are not always opened as soon as you're logged in (anyone or any program/malware can read the passwords).

Comment: "They will do by themselves once you installed / started them or used some functionality within these apps."  ok they did that, but on other ubuntu installation I deleted them, how could I recreate them for each app. Or at least for chrome?